# Insert url to new web query using cell url

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with a url. I want to make a macro that records from selecting data from a website using the url in cell e.g. B2 to reach the website. I have searched the internet and can't find the answer anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: You want to record your steps in a website? If so, Excel VBA is not the solution you should looking for :/

Comment: Nope just want to scrape several websites for data. all website urls contained in cells. My plan is to scrape a site go to next cell containing a url, scrape that site, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code may help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getWebData()

    Dim ini_wb As Workbook: Set ini_wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim aux_wb As Workbook
    Dim url As String

    ' Change the sheet name and cell address according to your needs
    url = ini_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set aux_wb = Workbooks.Open(url)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Note:** I have https://www.google.com in cell `B3` of `Sheet1`

HTH ;)